# Azure Cognitive Search Integration in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, azure-cognitive-search

Good day!

I just wanted some validation of my understanding that when we integrate Azure Cognitive Search in SharePoint, we cannot access the documents in the Azure, right? However, it is possible to navigate documents in the Office365 using ACS?

Basically, we can only index the files from SharePoint and can search the contents through Azure Portal using the Azure Cognitive Search?

This is what I have searched so far:

1. Index data from SharePoint document libraries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-sharepoint-online
2. Not possible to extend SharePoint to Azure Blob using ACS: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/how-to-setup-sharepoint-site-to-use-azure-blob-storage/m-p/331761

Sorry, I am still new in this field (basically, first year college, and I do not have a mentor to ask this).

Answer (score 2):

If you use Azure Search to Index Sharepoint data, these documents will be put in an Index inside the ACS service, you can then query this index that contains the documents by using not only the Azure portal, but any http client such as postman (querying through REST APIs) or any app accessing ACS through the available SDKs.See this

Search SDK for .NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-dotnet-sdk
Searching documents through REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents